# How to turn off Magic Lantern info in Live View?

Tags: canon, magic-lantern

This is annoying. I need to see the whole frame in Live View, including borders, to check the composition. So I try to turn off the all info in Live View by pressing the <kbd>INFO.</kbd> button. But when usual CANON info disappears, Magic Lantern Live View appears. I just need clear live view frame with no info! How do I turn Magic Lantern Live View info off?

Comment: Which camera are you using?

Comment: @MikeSowsun Canon EOS 700D and 600D.

Comment: I have Magic Lantern on my 5D3 and SL1 and don't have that problem.  I would remove Magic Lantern and then reinstall it to see if the problem goes away.

Answer (score 1):

You can also configure Magic Lantern to not show anything when you're in Live View.
The [(outdated) manual states](https://wiki.magiclantern.fm/userguide#global_draw):

> ### Global Draw
>
> Choose when to enable Magic Lantern overlay graphics: (zebra,
> cropmarks, histograms, audio meters, ML shooting info…):
>
> - in LiveView only
> - in QuickReview (photo mode outside LiveView) only
> - Both modes
> - Disabled

Alternatively you can configure the ["clear overlays"](https://wiki.magiclantern.fm/userguide#clear_overlays) function:

> ### Clear Overlays
>
> Clear bitmap overlays from LiveView display.
>
> - HalfShutter: Hold the shutter half-pressed, or the * button, or DOF preview for around 1 second to clear all the overlays from the Live View display (audio, zebra, crops, shutter speeds…).Tip: assign autofocus to * button (from Custom Functions, set Shutter/AE lock button = AE lock/AF).
> - WhenIdle: In this mode, all the overlays are erased from the screen (100% clean display) when the camera is idle (i.e. you don't press any buttons).
> - Always: In this mode, all the overlays are erased from the screen; you will have to change shooting settings blindly. You can still use the menus.Tip: this feature may be useful with External Recorders, since it removes the focus box and other graphics from the display.

Answer (score 0):

You can hold "SET" at startup to disable Magic Lantern for one boot !

You could, of course, also remove it... but it is good to keep it for when/if you need it !

[Source](https://wiki.magiclantern.fm/faq)